# CSS: Цвет смежных границ в таблицах при вёрстке

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица со смежными границами серого цвета. При прописывании цвета границы (синего) для конкретной TD-ячейки в таблице, цвет верхней и левой границ не меняется - остаётся серым.

Как перекрыть старый цвет?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid silver;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуй !important

Comment: !important не сработал. Сделал через JS окраску нижней границы у ячейки над выделенной, и границы справа у соседней слева.)

Comment: При этом точки по углам остались неокрашенными, хах

Comment: @Roman Boykov, кинь код или сайт, посмотрю что там у тебя

Comment: Легко воспроизводится. Я добавил код.

Answer (score 1):

Если ширина границы - чётная, то можно просто накрыть её outline'ом:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 4px solid silver;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  outline: 4px solid red;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```

Если нет, то, как минимум, в хроме и FF эта рамка немного съезжает:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid silver;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  outline-offset: -1.5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```

Можно исправить положив в ячейку div c `position: relative` и повесив на него тень, но тогда надо не забыть сбросить padding у ячейки.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  padding: 0; /* По умолчанию получается 1px */
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><div></div><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если таблица несложная и устраивает современный грид, то можно её превратить в grid:

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  width: fit-content;
  --border-width: 3px;
  padding: var(--border-width);
  gap: var(--border-width);
}

tbody, tr {
  display: contents;
}

td {
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: calc(0px - var(--border-width));
  border: var(--border-width) solid silver;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2) {
  border-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
  <tr><td><td><td><td><td></tr>
</table>
```